# ffmpeg.js build is missing defined format

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg.js

I'm attempting to encode files using `pcm_f32le` with the `f32le` format. I've defined both the encoder and format within the makefile present in the cloned ffmpeg.js repository:

```
WEBM_MUXERS = webm ogg null data f32le
WEBM_ENCODERS = libvpx_vp8 libopus pcm_f32le
```

If I print out available codecs using the `-codecs` option, I can see `pcm_f32le` as an available encoder. However, the `-formats` option is missing the `f32le` format. If I attempt to use the format to encode, ffmpeg complains that it isn't a available format.

I'm sure I'm missing something trivial. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `pcm_f32le` is also used as the format.